# Python replace whole word including initial special character

Tags: python, regex, replace, words

I have this piece of code:

```
import re


variable_to_be_replaced = '$VAR'
value_to_set = 'success'
sample_string = '$VAR VAR $$VAR $VAR1 $VAR1$VAR$VAR2 $VAR'

print re.sub(r'\b' + variable_to_be_replaced + r'\b', value_to_set, sample_string)
```

I'd like the output to be `'success VAR $success $VAR1 $VAR1success$VAR2 success'` and I can only modify the print statement. I know this doesn't work because the variable name starts with $. The delimiters should be the regular word delimiters (minus 1 starting $ symbol).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with this RegEx:

```
\$VAR(?=[\s\$]|$)
```

Which finds '$VAR' when there is a space or a $ after it. More specifically, I use [Positive Lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to identify parts of the string that are '$VAR ', '$VAR$', or if '$VAR' is the end of the string, and then I replace only the '$VAR' part of that match with the substitution string.

Check it out here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sbCyOo/3) with the substitution.

Output:

```
success VAR $success $VAR1 $VAR1success$VAR2 success
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with negative look ahead like so:

```
import re

s_str = '$VAR VAR $$VAR $VAR1 $VAR1$VAR$VAR2 $VAR'
print re.sub(r'\$VAR(?!\d)', r'success', s_str)
```

Output:

```
success VAR $success $VAR1 $VAR1success$VAR2 success
```

Regex:

`\$VAR(?!\d)` - Search for `'$VAR'` with negative look ahead of digit character

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/EgXlcD/1